# Centroid of volume of revolution

Tags: calculus, solid-of-revolution, centroid

Consider a solid generated by the curve $y^2 =ax^2+2bx+c$,rotated about the $x$-axis, and two plane surfaces at right angles to the latter, distance $h$ apart, and with areas $A$ and $B$. To prove that the centroid of the solid is at a distance $h/2 + (B-A)h^2/12V$ from $A$, where $V$ is the volume of the solid.

I have calculated $$V=\frac{(B+A)h}2 -\frac{\pi a h^3}6$$ by integration, but cannot see how to proceed further. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You define $A$ as an area, but then speak of the centroid being a certain distance from $A$. Areas are numbers. Centroid are points. There is no such thing as a distance from a number to a point.

Comment: Yes,sorry for that, I meant The final A to be the plane surface with area A,the distance being measured along the x axis

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use Pappus's ($2^{nd}$) Centroid Theorem: the volume of a planar area of revolution is the product of the area $A$ and the length of the path traced by its centroid $R$, i.e., $2\pi R$. The bottom line is that the volume is given simply by $V=2\pi RA$. I assume that that you can calculate the area, hence you can get centroid quite easily, i.e., $R=\frac{V}{2\pi A}$. (Be sure to calculate the area between the curve and the axis of revolution.)

Comment: Thanks for this,but I do not think Pappus' Theorem is applicable here. Area A (and B) are the areas of the planar boundaries of the volume of revolution,and are not rotated.

Answer (score 0):

I have now proved the result, by expressing the stated  result  in terms of integrals and comparing terms in the usual formula for the centroid. This method was somewhat laborious, and did not give any hint of a more elegant method!